# Using regex in verifyEquals()

Tags: java, regex, selenium

I have selenium test written in java, I want to use regular expression in verifyEquals() to match with

```
 selenium.getText(id="something")
```

can I use it like this?

```
verifyEquals("regexp: Regular Expression", selenium.getText("id=something"))
```

Comment: [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: http://automationtricks.blogspot.com/2010/05/selenium-regular-expression-and-pattern.html  In this post was written that I can use like this

Answer (score 0):

No.

But you can do this:

```
verifyTrue(selenium.getText(id="something").matches("someregex"));
```

NB: The regex you pass to `matches()` must match the *whole* string to return true.

Comment: http://automationtricks.blogspot.com/2010/05/selenium-regular-expression-and-pattern.html  In this post was written that I can use like this